# Vercel deploy Cannot resolve "~/api/index.js" from "/var/task/api/index.js"

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

My app is deployed on vercel. However, it's not working. In function logs it has following

```
FATAL  Cannot resolve "~/api/index.js" from "/var/task/api/index.js"
at Resolver.resolvePath (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:572:11)
at Server._requireMiddleware (node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:799:32)
at Server._normalizeMiddleware (node_modules/@nuenter code herext/server/dist/server.js:756:25)
at Server.resolveMiddleware (node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:824:23)
at Server.useMiddleware (node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:849:36)
at Server.setupMiddleware (node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:707:12)
at async Server.ready (node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:637:5)
at async Nuxt._init (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:719:7)
2020-08-21T06:58:37.024Z    da066c7e-660f-4f4e-b080-9dfca786aa73    ERROR   λ Error while 
initializing nuxt: Error: Cannot resolve "~/api/index.js" from "/var/task/api/index.js"
at Resolver.resolvePath (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:572:11)
at Server._requireMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:799:32)
at Server._normalizeMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:756:25)
at Server.resolveMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:824:23)
at Server.useMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:849:36)
at Server.setupMiddleware (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:707:12)
at async Server.ready (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:637:5)
at async Nuxt._init (/var/task/node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:719:7)
RequestId: da066c7e-660f-4f4e-b080-9dfca786aa73 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError'
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you follow [Nuxt-Vercel Builder](https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder), with serverMiddleware configured properly?

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": ["api/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: oh god! I spent hours on this. why is this not documented. By the way, thank you brother. this works like a charm. you saved my day!

Comment: another day saved here too!